# apache2 not sending logs to remote server via rsyslog

Tags: ubuntu, logging, apache2, rsyslog

both apache access & apache error logs not arriving on central server.
some logs are successfully arriving tho including: auth, authpriv, cron, daemon, kern, syslog logs.
what else do i need to get apache logs centralized?

**heres my testing lab setup ->**
server and clients are: Apache/2.4.41 running on Ubuntu Server 20.04 Linux 5.4.0-42.
rsyslog server and clients are: 8.2001.0.
only firewall is default iptables and ufw install.

**server rsyslog config file is /etc/rsyslog.d/01-server.conf is:**

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$template RemoteServer, "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%SYSLOGFACILITY-TEXT%.log"
*.* ?RemoteServer
local3.*                        /local/logs/httpd-error
local4.*                        /local/logs/httpd-access
```

**client rsyslog config file is /etc/rsyslog.d/01-client.conf is:**

```
$WorkDirectory /var/log/rsyslogspools
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
local3.* @@192.168.1.88:514
local4.* @@192.168.1.88:514
*.*     @@192.168.1.88:514
```

**client apache config file /etc/rsyslog.d/apache.conf is:**

```
$ModLoad imfile
# Default Apache Error Log
$InputFileName /var/log/httpd/error_log
$InputFileTag httpd-error-default:
$InputFileStateFile stat-httpd-error
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
# Default Apache Access Log
$InputFileName /var/log/httpd/access_log
$InputFileTag httpd-access-default:
$InputFileStateFile stat-httpd-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local4
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollInterval 10
```

this lab is running on virtualbox, rsyslog client server is working for most logs just not apache

Comment: I assume you have configured apache to use syslog for logging? (see mod_syslog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache files monitoring should use the ubuntu/debian path instead of red-hat/centos (/var/log/httpd/error_log VS /var/log/apache2/error.log)

So change /etc/rsyslog.d/apache.conf to

```
$ModLoad imfile
# Default Apache Error Log
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/error.log
$InputFileTag httpd-error-default:
$InputFileStateFile stat-httpd-error
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
# Default Apache Access Log
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/access.log
$InputFileTag httpd-access-default:
$InputFileStateFile stat-httpd-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local4
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollInterval 10
```